# Creating User name and Password for the application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have 2 files named `Login.jsp`, `NewChart.jsp`. I am using `Login.jsp` to enter my password and user name and i am retriving user name and password from the mysql database.
In a browser if i enter the url of the `NewChart.jsp`, it is displaying the chart.
How to avoid this and i should access chart only through `Login.jsp`?

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways I can think of :-

1. Move the *NewChart.jsp* file under **WEB-INF**  of your Servlet Container . From the *Login.jsp* `redirect` or `forward` to the *NewChart.jsp.*
2. Write a filter and check for some session attribute before the request arrives for the *NewChart.jsp*. Set the session attribute on Login.

Answer (score 1):

you need to manage session and at the time of login set attribute in session and very first in NewChart,jsp check whether that attibute set in seession if so then go ahead otherwise direct redirect to login.jsp

Answer (score 1):

There a built-in security mechanisms and you should use them, security is complicated and there are many ways to get it wrong.

If you're using Tomcat, you can use a [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) to secure your application